# Getting an exception with datetime diff

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I've 2 buttons on my webpage. And when I hit the first button, the system time gets updated in `starttime` of my sql table, and when I hit a stop, The end time has to be updated and the difference between both should be updated in anothere table. I've using the below queries.

To update the end time and to update the total time.

```
update breakstable set endtime = ?, TotalBreakTime = (? - StartTime)  where userid = ? 
and endtime is NULL
```

here first 2 `?`s refers to a button click that happens and another `?` for the logged in userId getting captured from session.

update another table with the sum of the `totalbreaktime`.

```
MERGE Time_Tracker as target using (SELECT USERID, CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),
SUM(DATEDIFF(Second, '19000101', TotalBreakTime))/60.0) as ColumnWithBreaksCount FROM 
BreaksTable where CONVERT(Date, StartTime) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE()) GROUP BY USERID) 
as source ON target.USERID = source.USERID WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET BREAKS = source.ColumnWithBreaksCount;"
```

**problem:**

I start my time, go on a break and return after an hour and half and i hit the stop button. Instead of updating the table it is giving me the below Exception.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The datediff
>   function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating
>   two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less
>   precise datepart.

and the JDBC Exception (For Java guys) is as below.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The datediff function
>   resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two
>   date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less
>   precise datepart.     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1454)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:388)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:338)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:185)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:160)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:306)
>     at
>   org.DAO.UpdateEndTimeDAO.UpdateEndTimeDetails(UpdateEndTimeDAO.java:48)
>     at org.servlet.UpdateEndTime.doPost(UpdateEndTime.java:38)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at Filter.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:58)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

And the exception points to the second query declared in my question.

If the time is less, say like 2 min or 3 mins, it is updating without any issue.

please where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

My Breaks table looks like below

[image]

Instead of null, this should be the end time captured on button click

And my Time tracker looks like below.

[image]

instead of `4.97` in above screenshot it should be the sum of the `totalbreaktime` from my first screenshot.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell you are taking the difference between the first of January 1900 and some date. `datediff` can only bridge 68 years worth of seconds, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.110).aspx As you are dividing by 60 anyway, why not just use `datediff(minutes, ...)` or rethink what you are doing at all.

Comment: because the number of seconds between 1 jan 1900 and the current date and time is about 3,681,185,640.  This is greater than a 32 bit integer can hold, and the `datediff` function is limted to that.

Comment: BTW: I suggest that you also post 1) code with example values used and 2) the values inserted.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, Thanks for pointing it out. Attached a screen of my table

Comment: Hi @CharlesBretana, Mark Rotteveel, Yes I saw it now, but can you please let me know how can I fix this?

Comment: You can calculate the difference between the actual start date and the end date, instead of from 1 jan 1900 (other Logic will need to change), or, as @Mark suggested, use minutes instead of seconds. How accurate do you need to be for this?

Comment: Looks like somewhere you inserted the value intended for `EndTime` into `TotalBreakTime`.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, Sorry to say, I need it in seconds and then I want to convert that into minutes

Comment: Have you considered instead to just insert the number of seconds, instead of abusing a datetime as an interval type?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Sorry I don't know about it. I'm into backend with Java, but there was a requirement and followed some other SO posts and made it up :(. And the `TotalBreakTime` should be the difference between the end and start times.

Comment: Then just subtract the two dates (forget the datediff)  and multiply by 86400.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel,  And I've given the `TotalBreakTime` to the `starttime` as the user once he starts the timer, he should be ending it (hitting a stop) to continue. That's how the `TotalBreakTime` is calculated by using the difference.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, did you mean like `CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),
SUM(DATEDIFF(Second, '19000101', TotalBreakTime))/60.0) as ColumnWithBreaksCount` to `CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),
SUM(endtime - starttime) * 86400) as ColumnWithBreaksCount`?

Comment: no, use cast like this:  `select cast(cast(getdate() as float) * 86400 as bigint)`.  It gives number of seconds since 1 jan 1900.

Answer (score 0):

This is because DATETIME functions like DATEDIFF, DATEADD etc. accept and returns integer (INT) data type. Limit of the data type is 2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647).

So if you add -2147483648 to TotalBreakTime. It returns "1948-08-08 14:01:46.000"

```
SELECT DATEADD(SS,CAST(-2147483648 AS BIGINT),'2016-08-26 17:15:54.000');
```

And more the the limit of datatype returns ERROR.

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Because date difference in second is too large (out of limit of datatype) between the dates in the query. It returns the error.

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),
SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(Second, '19000101', '2016-08-26 17:15:54.000') AS BIGINT))/60.0)
```

I would suggest to discuss logic with you team resolve the issue accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
MERGE Time_Tracker as target 
   using 
    (SELECT USERID, 
        Sum(cast(cast(TotalBreakTime as float) 
              * 86400 as bigint)) ColumnWithBreaksCount
     FROM BreaksTable b 
     Where datediff(day, StartTime, GETDATE()) = 0
     GROUP BY USERID) source 
ON target.USERID = source.USERID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET BREAKS = source.ColumnWithBreaksCount;"
```