# Aggregate function exception when I run my query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is an extension of my previous question([Getting an exception with datetime diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168477/getting-an-exception-with-datetime-diff/39173592#39173592)), but this time i've made my `totalbreaktime` to be a `float` and below is my new query.

```
MERGE Time_Tracker as target using (SELECT USERID, cast(DATEDIFF(second,starttime,endtime)/60.0 as numeric(36,2)) as ColumnWithBreaksCount FROM BreaksTable 
where CONVERT(Date, StartTime) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE()) GROUP BY USERID) as source ON target.USERID = source.USERID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET BREAKS = source.ColumnWithBreaksCount;
```

This time when I run this query, I'm getting the below Exception.

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'BreaksTable.StartTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'BreaksTable.EndTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

**problem:**

1. As discussed in my previous question, I want to update my `Time_tracker.breaks` as sum of the `breakstable.totalbreaktime` based on the date.
2. When I run the query(the previous one), it is considering all the data instead of the current date's data.

And my table data is as below.

**Time_Tracker**

[image]

**BreaksTable**

[image]

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this subquery in your query:

```
SELECT USERID,
       cast(DATEDIFF(second, starttime, endtime)/60.0 as numeric(36,2)) as ColumnWithBreaksCount
FROM BreaksTable 
WHERE CONVERT(Date, StartTime) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE())
GROUP BY USERID;
```

The second column is not an aggregated column, nor are the columns in the expression in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Hence the error.

I can speculate that you actually want a `SUM()` for the second column:

```
MERGE Time_Tracker as target using
      (SELECT USERID,
              cast(SUM(DATEDIFF(second, starttime, endtime)) / 60.0 as numeric(36,2)) as ColumnWithBreaksCount
       FROM BreaksTable 
       WHERE CONVERT(Date, StartTime) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE())
       GROUP BY USERID
      ) as source
      ON target.USERID = source.USERID 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET BREAKS = source.ColumnWithBreaksCount;
```

Comment: Hi Friend, this worked awesome, but there is small problem I'm unable to do a `where` like where `CONVERT(Date, BreaksTable.StartTime) = CONVERT(Date, Time_Tracker.Login)`, when I run this this gives me exception as `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.`